# How to get the ip address of veth in a bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

In my environment, there're three veth in the bridge:

```
$ brctl show virbr1
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
virbr1          8000.52540071337a       yes             eth1
                                                        virbr1-nic
                                                        vnet1
```

and I can get the mac address of them:

```
$ brctl showmacs virbr1          
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  3     52:54:00:25:7a:ab       yes                0.00
  3     52:54:00:25:7a:ab       yes                0.00
  3     52:54:00:99:67:68       no                 9.15
  2     52:54:00:99:d8:05       no                 8.48
  2     fe:54:00:99:d8:05       yes                0.00
  2     fe:54:00:99:d8:05       yes                0.00
```

But how I can get the IP adress of those veth in bridge? Currently, I can get the IP address by `arp`; is there any other way to get more detail?

```
~$ sudo arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.252.246          ether   52:54:00:99:d8:05   C                     virbr1
192.168.252.254          ether   52:54:00:99:67:68   C                     virbr1
192.168.252.83           ether   52:54:00:99:d8:05   C                     virbr1
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address doesn't belong to your bridge or to your veth. (Bridge members do not have IP addresses – or even MAC addresses; the IP or MAC address of the bridge is what's used for everything.)

It's the host **on the other end** of the 'veth' pair (the other end of the virtual Ethernet cable) that actually has the IP address you're seeing in the ARP cache, or the MAC address you're seeing in the bridge cache.

So because the addresses belong not to a local interface but to a completely separate host on the "other end" of the virtual cable, there is no locally available API to get more detail. The only way for your bridge to know anything at all is by learning from packets it has received from the other host.

Although since veth is inherently local (the "other end" is a container on the same machine), you can cheat and look up the information directly from the other network namespace:

1. Run `ip -d link ls vnet1` to find the interface's 'link-netnsid' (i.e. the netnsid of the peer veth). It seems it's [not always](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441987/2168) assigned, but in my case it appears to be present.
2. Run `sudo lsns -t net` to list network namespaces with their IDs, along with a process that belongs to that namespace; look for a process that has a matching netnsid.
3. Run `nsenter --net -t <PID> ip addr` to list the addresses visible inside that namespace.

If you already know which container a given veth belongs to, you can find its PIDs in another way, e.g. from the container manager (any process will do, not necessarily the "init" process) and skip to step 3.

Comment: Got that! That's really helpful, thanks very much :)